# WSO2 enterprise integrator. - datasource on server

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

It is possible deploy datasource  in WSO2 EI on server without GUI? I try find something on internet but i found only create datasource in GUI.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use Integration Studio for this purpose. Please refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Managing+Data+Integration+Artifacts+via+Tooling#ManagingDataIntegrationArtifactsviaTooling-Step2:Creatingthedatasourceconnection.

You can create a carbon application in the tooling and deploy it to the server without using GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your datasource into master-datasources.xml that is located in EI_HOME\conf\datasources\master-datasources.xml

here is the example code:

```
<datasource>
    <name>WSO2_ESB_LOGS_DB</name>
    <description/>
    <jndiConfig>
        <name>jdbc/WSO2EsbLogsDB</name>
    </jndiConfig>
    <definition type="RDBMS">
        <configuration>
            <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb</url>
            <username>myusername</username>
            <password>mypassword</password>
            <driverClassName>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClassName>
            <maxActive>50</maxActive>
            <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
            <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
            <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
            <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
            <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
        </configuration>
    </definition>
</datasource>
```

Comment: it's possible to create a separate file for your custom datasource but it should be named `*-datasources.xml`. Note: you have to restart server to apply datasource defined in a file.

Comment: Yes, but if i create datasource in tenant from  gui i dont see any changes on server.  do you know where is it file on server?   i try create new datasource in my new tenant and master-datasource.xml is without my datasource